# VB Script to copy each line in a csv file the number of times specified by a column in the file

Tags: vb.net, file, text, copy, line

I have a csv data file (first row column headers, subsequent rows data); the last column contains a number.
I need a script that will read the csv file and output to another file, which replicates each line in the input file the number of times in the last column; ideally with an extra column for a counter that restarts at 1 for each line in the input file
e.g. with this input file:

```
    Name,ID,Lines
    Fred Smith,102,2
    Elaine Edwards,576,1
    Joe Bloggs,987,3
```

The output file would be this:

```
    Name,ID,Lines,Counter
    Fred Smith,102,2,1
    Fred Smith,102,2,2
    Elaine Edwards,576,1 
    Joe Bloggs,987,3,1
    Joe Bloggs,987,3,2
    Joe Bloggs,987,3,3
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this gratefully received.

I'm new to vb scripting so not sure how to go about this.

Comment: It's not for us to just write your code for you. You need to spend the time and make the effort to work out what the logic is - how would you do it if it was a manual process - then formalise that into an algorithm and finally try to write code to implement the algorithm. If you encounter a specific issue along the way then you can ask about that specifically. Just telling us what you want the result to be and expecting us to do the rest is not what this site is for. Questions like that may be acceptable at various forums but not here.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out, see below. I'm sure there's a more elegant way of treating the first line in the csv file (which has the column headings) differently, but it does the job.

```
    Dim objFSO, NoReqd, arr, i,j 
    j=1
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    InputFile = "C:\Labels.csv"
    OutputFile = "c:\labels_extended.csv"
    set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile,1)
    set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OutputFile,2,True)
    do until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strContent=objFile.ReadLine
        arr = Split(strContent,",",-1)
        NoReqd=arr(5)
        If j=1 then 
            outFile.WriteLine strContent & "," & "Box No"
        else 
            for i = 1 to NoReqd
                finaltext = strcontent & "," & i
                outFile.WriteLine finaltext
            next
        End If
        j=j+1
    Loop
    outFile.Close
    objFile.Close
```